# SSIS Component Development Resources

Tags: resources, ssis, components

I've been tasked with developing SSIS Components for my company, that range in complexity.  Developing the components as individual applications wouldn't be an issue for me but I'm really struggling to find SSIS Component development resources.  The coding isn't an issue but I'm struggling to find resources to explain the architecture.  I'm aware that there are around 5 different types of component and I'm currently unsure which ones I would be using.  The best resource I've found are the last few chapters of the SSIS SAMS Unleashed book.  So my question is can anyone recommend any resources?  I can't believe there aren't more examples or tutorials around.  The resources I have located so far are below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136025.aspx  MSDN Resource
http://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/ccnv/ - Benny Austin Blog on Credit Card Validation
http://msftisprodsamples.codeplex.com/ - CodePlex SSIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my honest opinion, you shouldn't overtly depend on big books and references.
I believe in moving one step, and then looking up and learning things you encounter.

That way you need to counter the entire behemoth at one shot, while still learning fast and useful things.

You can use [SQL Server Central](http://sqlservercentral.com) as source for most of the queries about architecture, design principles and technical challenges faced by people.[SSIS Talk](http://ssistalk.com) is another blog where you can see descriptions about challenges and problems.

There were many more pages I used to refer and read through when I was working on SSIS. I would have to dig up my delicious account to fetch. Maybe I will edit and update here later in the evening.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I've read a fair few articles but none of them really explain where to start.  The programming isn't an issue it's just I'm not sure where I start except create a new class library and adding some relevant references.

Comment: if u are looking for details regarding the inner working of SSIS engine, i am afraid I can't remember any such references. You can get a good idea of how it works by reading some basic stuff, preparing some simple packages and testing some scenarios. nothing more would be required for you to get started

Comment: I've got a traning course later this week on how to use SSIS.  I guess that would be a good place to start.  I'm just struggling to understand exactly where to start with each of the component types.  I've got my list of requirements and implementing them into an application would be easy but into an SSIS component I'm struggling where to start.  Its just frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of information to find online. A good place to start is with SQL Server Books Online:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment but not exactly what I was looking for.  The coding isn't an issue, I'm just not sure where to start.  I learn quicker from examples than just reading the theory.